# how can I typecast NewProxyConnection into AS400JDBCConnection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, ibm-midrange, spring-aop

I am new to Spring . I am using ComboPooledDataSource for connection pooling in Spring.
I am using the AS400 for making the connection.
My problem is that when I am using this connection and try to typecast this
AS400JDBCConnection as400Conn = (AS400JDBCConnection)conn;
It gives the ClassCastCastException because the connection object returned by the ComboPooledDataSource is of type NewProxyConnection how can I typecast it into AS400JDBCConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring does support unwrapping the proxied ComboPooledDataSource object.  If you are using JdbcTemplate, you can set the nativeJdbcExtractor property to an appropriate object.  So any place you can retrieve a native Connection or even any of the derived objects (like ResultSet) will be native.

The JavaDoc for the NativeJdbcExtractor interface for a list of supported classes.  That can help you decide which implementation works for you application.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to cast to `AS400JDBCConnection`. All relevant methods should be available through the `Connection` interface.

What you are dealing with is not the actual Connection object (the AS400JDBCConnection), but a proxy Object that is wrapped around it and manages access to the original Connection Object. The different proxy mechanisms are explained in [Understanding AOP Proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)

Update responding to comments: Access to the Method [`AS400JDBCConnection.getServerJobIdentifier()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/info/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCConnection.html#getServerJobIdentifier%28%29) is needed. Then you will have to switch to CGLib proxying (explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types)).

Comment: Dear Sean actually I want to do this   AS400JDBCConnection as400Conn = (AS400JDBCConnection)conn;
  String serverJobIdentifier = as400Conn.getServerJobIdentifier();
the main reason I have to typecast it into AS400JDBCConnection