# Gets the inner connection from the ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: spring

How to get the inner connection object from the ComboPooledDataSource.

Comment: I take it this is a rephrased version of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305317/how-can-i-typecast-newproxyconnection-into-as400jdbcconnection). I'm not sure this rephrasing will help. I don't think this has anything to do with the `ComboPooledDataSource`, JDK proxies are your problem, as I wrote in the other question's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComboPooledDataSource (assuming it's the c3p0 framework) implements javax.sql.DataSource so just calling [`getConnection()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection%28%29) should work.

Comment: getConnection() returns the type of connection is NewProxyConnection I want the connection of type AS400JDBCConnection.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had explained this in your question. Reading Sean Patrick Floyd:s comment above, and your previous question - have you tried Sean:s suggestion, switching to CGLIB proxying instead? That is probably the best way forward.

Comment: No I am no tried Sean's suggestion. Because for this I have to implement AOP in my project. Actually my problem is that I have configured the ComboPooledDataSource and when i use the getConnection() object it returns the object type is NewProxyConnection but I want it should return AS400JDBCConnection.